# VB.net TextBox won't be focused() with Keydown event

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox

I want to set a focus to the specific `textbox` when I press ALT+SOME KEY.

However, when I press the shortcut key combination, it focuses something else. Even I pressed CTRL+P, the `txtAuthor` got no focus at all while some strange `Button control` or another `textbox` got focus.

I checked that there is no duplicated key combinations. eg: &Press Here ..

plus : It is confirmed by Debugging that when I press Alt+Q, for example, the `txtQueue.Focus()` code below is executed. But, somehow txtQueue won't be focused.

plus : `KeyPreview` is set to `True`

```
Private Sub frmEdit_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown


    'Alt+Q
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Q AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Alt Then
        txtQueue.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Alt+D
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.D AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Alt Then
        txtDynamic.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Alt+K
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.K AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Alt Then
        txtTime.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Alt+P
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.P AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Alt Then
        txtAlgorithm.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If


End Sub
```

THank you!

Comment: The code is wrong, it forgets to set e.Handled = True.  So anything is possible, another mnemonic or shortcut can execute after this and mess up your focus.

Comment: Also this code assumes that the form is selected, what is not a too easily controlable issue (for example: if a textbox contained by the form, is selected, your code wouldn't be triggered). It seems that you should rely on global hooks (i.e., allowing the code to be called every time the given combination of keys is pressed independently upon the selected control).

Comment: @HansPassant actually I removed e.Handled=True because it didn't fix the problem. I added that code again but nothing changed..

Comment: KeyPreview is a VB6 compatibility property, it isn't the best way to do this since there are other shortcut key handlers that run before this.  The best way is the Winforms way, override the ProcessCmdKey() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

overriding the ProcessCmdKey() works!

I don't know the reason, however, intermittently ProcessCmdKey() doesn't work even though I clicked the Form, Buttons inside the Form etc...

Answer (score 0):

I would set breakpoint as you seem to have done to check that the correct focus is set but then continue stepping through the code (F8 in VStudio) to check that nothing then moves the focus elsewhere. Does the same control always get focus?

Also I would change your code to incorporate a select case...

```
Private Sub frmEdit_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown

If e.Modifiers = Key.Alt Then

    Select Case (e.KeyCode)

        'Alt+Q
        Case Keys.Q 
            txtQueue.Focus()
            Exit Select

        'Alt+D
        Case Keys.D 
            txtDynamic.Focus()
            Exit Select

        'Alt+K
        Case Keys.K 
            txtTime.Focus()
            Exit Select

        'Alt+P
        Case Keys.P 
            txtAlgorithm.Focus()
            Exit Select
    End Select

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You aren't addressing the problem: recommending to debug the code does not represent a solution; and replacing the original code with Select Case would certainly not correct any problem. All this sounds more like a comment than like an answer to me.

Comment: In a way I would agree.. but it may point out that somewhere else in the code the focus is being changed and thus solution. The change to Select Case is better shown in an answer where code can be displayed in block. But point taken.

Comment: It is weird that when I press ALT+D it correctly focuses `txtDynamic`, while when I press ALT+Q, it focuses some unexpected `Button Control` (always the same Button when I press ALT+Q). Is there any **hidden** short-cut key configuring part?

Comment: @klados I explained it in my comment above: your code is associated to a control (the main form). If the main form is not selected, your code wouldn't be executed. Every time the form is selected, your code would be executed IF applicable (as explained by Hans above). Make sure that the conditions are met and that you describe the problem properly, that is: is certainly the main form being selected when the code misbehaves?

Comment: Mych, the fact of using one or other modifier or one or other key or if statements or case select, does not change anything (that's why my first comment). But there are quite a few involved issues which the OP is not mentioning and thus proposing solutions is the same than blindly guessing: he should be much more clear regarding the (relevant) conditions.

Comment: @varocarbas It seems that my 'Answer' was posted before or at the same time as the first comment by Hans and as such I had not seen these when making my comment to this thread. Looking at yours and Hans's comments I can see to what you are referring.

Comment: @varocarbas I checked the focus thing. I think it is okay because ALK+K is correctly working. For the checking, I put the code in a function that handles txtDynamic.KeyDown, then pressed the ALT+Q with txtDynamic to be focused. However, it also fails..

Comment: Mych, no problem. Just comment you this to extend your answer further.

Comment: @klados But in your second test a different element is selected (i.e., the firstly selected textbox). Just click on the form before trying each combination and everything should work. Note that keeping track of the exact control being selected is not easy, unless being something like a textbox in which you are writing. For hotkeys is usually better relying on global hooks to avoid problems (always work).

Comment: @varocarbas thanks for suggesting that. I will implement and replace it.

Comment: @varocarbas I have another question. Sometimes even if I set Me.Focus() or Panel1.Focus(), they seem to be not focused. While, strangely, when a Panel1 is focused, any other controls won't get focused programatically; Button1.Focus() is not working(not focused). Is there any clear answer? Thanks!

Comment: @klados As far as I know, Focus() works always. Why you think that the given control is not being focused? Perhaps it is focused but then immediately (1ms later) another control gets the focus because of whatever reason (only one control can have the focus every time). Also, in some controls, the highlighting is more relevant than in other ones; perhaps it has the focus but you cannot even see it. Bear in mind that the focus is just for "internal purposes", that is, telling the control which is active in the given thread; the highlighting is something secondary.